# How to decompress a []byte content in gzip format that gives an error when unmarshaling

Tags: utf-8, go

I'm making a request to an API, which with I get a `[]byte` out of the response (`ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`). I'm trying to unmarshal this content, but seems to be not encoded on utf-8 format, as unmarshal returns an error. I'm trying this to do so:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "some/api"
)

func main() {
    content := api.SomeAPI.SomeRequest() // []byte variable
    var data interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(content, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Data from response", data)
}
```

I get as an error that `invalid character '\x1f' looking for beginning of value`. For the record, the response includes in the header that `Content-Type:[application/json; charset=utf-8]`.

How can I decode `content` to avoid these invalid characters when unmarshaling?

**Edit**

This is the hexdump of `content`: [play.golang.org/p/oJ5mqERAmj](http://play.golang.org/p/oJ5mqERAmj)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Judging by your hex dump you are receiving gzip encoded data so you'll need to use [compress/gzip](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/) to decode it first.

Try something like this

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "some/api"
)

func main() {
    content := api.SomeAPI.SomeRequest() // []byte variable

    // decompress the content into an io.Reader
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(content)
    reader, err := gzip.NewReader(buf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Use the stream interface to decode json from the io.Reader
    var data interface{}
    dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)
    err = dec.Decode(&data)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Data from response", data)
}
```

**Previous**

Character `\x1f` is the unit separator character in ASCII and UTF-8.  It is never part of an UTF-8 encoding, however can be used to mark off different bits of text.  A string with an `\x1f` can valid UTF-8 but not valid json as far as I know.

I think you need to read the API specification closely to find out what they are using the `\x1f` markers for, but in the meantime you could try removing them and see what happens, eg

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte("hello\x1fGoodbye")
    fmt.Printf("b was %q\n", b)
    b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte{0x1f}, []byte{' '}, -1)
    fmt.Printf("b is now %q\n", b)
}
```

Prints

```
b was "hello\x1fGoodbye"
b is now "hello Goodbye"
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/MQEIPnG-MD)

Comment: Basically what happens is that I find new invalid characters when introducing this fix: `invalid character '\u008b' looking for beginning of value`. I don't think replacing all of them one by one is the solution.

Comment: That is another ASCII control character... You'd better post a hex dump of what you actually received!

Comment: You can edit again and remove the "(untested)", because I did it and it works, thanks!

Comment: Thank you!
I have been looking for this solution and thought for so long.  I was being directed and thought this was ndjson as a response and I was trying to unmarshal that, which doesn't work.